# Simulate mouse hover on an item of QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

In Qt package, is it possible to achieve highlighting (as seen when hovering with the mouse) of an item in `QTreeView` programmatically?

I am able to select the item and it gives a similar impression, but I cannot use this method (since I am using selections in some other place).

The last option would be to store a flag in the item itself and return a background or a font from data() method for some role. But this approach seems very tedious.

[image]

Comment: Setting background color for the corresponding role in the model's `data()` function seems to be the right approach, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following vahancho advice.

In my model I have added the following in the `data(QModelIndex index)` method:

```
if (role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole)
{
    if (HasHighlighted && (index == LastHighlightedIndex))
    {
        return qVariantFromValue(QColor(229, 243, 255)); //highlighting color, at least on Windows10
    }
}
```

To highlight I call

```
void TreeModel::SetHighlighted(QModelIndex & index)
{
    if (index != LastHighlightedIndex || !HasHighlighted)
    {
        if (HasHighlighted)
        {
            emit dataChanged(LastHighlightedIndex, LastHighlightedIndex); //clearing previous highlighted 
        }
        LastHighlightedIndex = index;
        HasHighlighted = true;
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
    }

}
```

In my case I use a proxy so I need to get the right index: with the `GetModelIndex` method

```
void CustomTreeView::SimulateHover(QModelIndex index)
{
    TreeProxyModel *proxy = dynamic_cast<TreeProxyModel*>(this->model());
    if (proxy != nullptr)
    {
        proxy->model()->SetHighlighted(proxy->GetModelIndex(index));
    }
}
```

-

```
QModelIndex TreeProxyModel::GetModelIndex(QModelIndex & index)
    {
        return mapToSource(index);
    }
```

In addition to clear last hover:

```
void CustomTreeView::ClearSimulatedHover()
{
    TreeProxyModel *proxy = dynamic_cast<TreeProxyModel*>(this->model());
    if (proxy != nullptr)
    {
        proxy->model()->ClearHighlighted();
    }
}
```